# Javascript Replace HTML Characters

Tags: javascript

I am a total noob on Javascript. What I want is to have a search form, and the input to the form should change the url, then it will open a new tab with the new url.

For example, when I enter 'production', the url will become http://production-test.com/test/, then a new tab will open with the new url.

I know that this should be in Javascript, but I don't know how it will be able to return back the new url.

I have this html so far which does not work at all.

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function change_url(result) {
     #var result = document.getElementById().value;
     var new_url = "http://" + result + "-test.com/test/';
     # open new window with the new url
 }

 <form id="search-box" name="search_box" method="get" 
action="http://variable-test.com/test/" target="_blank"">

 <input id="search-text" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
class="form-text-box no-focus" name="c" value="" aria-haspopup="true">
 <input type="radio" id="rel" name="sort" value="1" onchange="saveType('rel');" /><span data-message="TypeOp1">Relevance</span><br />

 <input id="search-button" type="submit" />
```

Comment: There has been progress. Thanks to Dr. Molle. But now I don't know how to pass the parameters? From Dr. Molle script... form.action = ".../test/?" + "new_paramters". For some reason, anything after the question mark is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming your final goal is not only to open the new url in a new tab/window and you also want to send the form to the new url in the new tab/window:**

You may change the action of the form before submitting the form:

```
function change_url(form) { 
     var result = document.getElementById('inputId').value;        
     form.action = "http://" + result + "-test.com/test/";
     return true;
 }
```

and add this to the form-tag:

```
onsubmit="return change_url(this)"
```

The form will be sended now to the new url and into a new window/tab (because you set the target to `"_blank"`)

Comment: Hmm. Something is not right. It is still using the url that I specified in the form. Where can I paste the new code? Maybe I am not putting it in the right place.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the **result** inside the function, it's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working. It is still using the url in the form.

Comment: You must provide the correct ID of the textbox to getElementById()

Comment: do you mean something like document.getElementById(c).value?

Comment: Yes. See a demo, it contains all the necessary stuff : http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/AhcsP/

Comment: the demo really looks good. But how do I pass the parameters? form.action = ".../test/?" + "new_paramters". For some reason, anything after the question mark is dicarded.

Comment: As you usually do it when a form has the method GET: with form-elements. As you can see there already will be a parameter "search-text", it's coming from the first input.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, when I pass the parameter, I would like javascript to check it and re-process it. So, if I pass 'test' as the parameter, the function will check if it is 'test' and add something in the url like ... ?search-test=test&another_search=hello

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open`

```
window.open(new_url);
```

If you prefer the window to open in a new tab / window, pass in '_blank' as second argument

```
window.open(new_url, '_blank');
```

Comment: but the html will still open the form on its own without even calling the javascript function

Comment: I guess I am looking for a Javascript function / tutorial that would create a form with textbox and radio buttons, then I can manipulate the content of the form, then open a new tab.

Comment: Sorry not really sure what you want now >.<, I'm basing my answer on your requirement that says `when I enter 'production', the url will become http://production-test.com/test/, then a new tab will open with the new url.`